# How to pass vector object to main method?

Tags: java, object, constructor

- Define the class `Passenger` and `TrainCoach` and create an object of `TrainCoach` from `String[]`
- Define a class `Passenger` having the fields name (`String`), age (`int`), gender (`char`: M/F), weight (`int`)
- Define a class `TrainCoach` having the fields `Passenger[] passengers`.
- Define the class Train and the functions in it. The class Train has the field Vector coaches.
  Given a Vector as input, create the object Train where each String[] is similar to the one that was given as input to TrainCoach above.

Following is what I did.But I stuck in the Train class.I m not getting how to pass a vector object to main method.I tried following:

**Passenger Class:**

```
package Passenger;

 public class Passenger {
    String name;
    int age;
    char gender;
    int weight;  
    public Passenger(){}
        public Passenger(String data){
                String[] s=data.split(":");
                this.name=s[0];
                this.age=Integer.parseInt(s[1]);
                this.gender=s[2].charAt(0);
                this.weight=Integer.parseInt(s[3]);
        }
        public Passenger[] makePassenger(String[] input){
            Passenger[] passengers=new Passenger[input.length];
            for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++){
                passengers[i]=new Passenger(input[i]);
            }
            return passengers;
        }
}
```

**TrainCoach Class:**
    package Passenger;

```
public class TrainCoach {
    Passenger[] passengers;
    static char gender;
    public TrainCoach(){}
    public TrainCoach(Passenger[] passengers){
        this.passengers=passengers;
    }
    public TrainCoach(String[] data){
        Passenger[] passengers=new Passenger[data.length];
                for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    passengers[i]=new Passenger(data[i]);
                }
                this.passengers=passengers;     
    }
    public static class PassengerTest{

        public static void main(String[] args){
            String[] str={"Amit Sharma:24:M:72","Rahul:12:M:55"};
            Passenger pass=new Passenger();
            Passenger[] passenger=pass.makePassenger(str);
            TrainCoach traincoach=new TrainCoach(passenger);
            int c=traincoach.numberOfPassengers();
            int d=traincoach.numberOfChildren();
            int b=traincoach.totalWeight();
            int a=traincoach.numberOf(gender);
            System.out.print(c+","+d+","+b+","+a);
        }
    }
    public int numberOfPassengers(){
        return this.passengers.length;
    }
    public int numberOfChildren(){
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<passengers.length;i++){
            if(passengers[i].age < 16){
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
    public int totalWeight(){
        int sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<passengers.length;i++){
            sum+=passengers[i].weight;
        }
        return sum;
    }
    public int numberOf(char gender){
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<passengers.length;i++){
            if(passengers[i].gender=='M'){
                count++;
            }
            else if(passengers[i].gender=='F'){
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

**Train Class:**

```
package Passenger;

import java.util.Vector;

public class Train{

    Vector<TrainCoach>coaches;

    public Train(){}
    public Train(Vector<String[]> data){
        for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++){
            coaches.addElement(new TrainCoach(data.elementAt(i)));
        }
        this.coaches=coaches;
    }
    public static  class PassTrain{

        public static void main(String[] s){
            Passenger p=new Passenger();
            Passenger[] passenger =p.makePassenger(s);
            Vector<String[]> tc=new Vector<String[]>();
                    tc.addAll(tc);
            Train t=new Train(tc);
            int c=tc.numberOfPassengers();
            System.out.print(c);
        }
    }
    public int numberOfPassengers(){
        int numOfPassengersInTrain = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < coaches.size(); i++){
            numOfPassengersInTrain += this.coaches.elementAt(i).numberOfPassengers();
        }
        return(numOfPassengersInTrain);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can not. Think about your design once more

Comment: I know this is wrong but I m unable to find out.

Comment: I would recommend working through these tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html

Comment: probably your input should be a String[] of data which you should pass to the Passenger(String) constructor. from that you can create the coach objects which you can then pass to the constructor of Train. Because the main() method has signature main(String[]) therefore you can't pass a Vector Object...

Comment: Do you have to use `System.in`?

Comment: Why are you interested in using a `Vector`? It is an obsolete collection like `Hashtable`.

Comment: @Tiny it's spelled `Hashtable`.

Comment: The line `tc.addAll(tc)` will do nothing no matter what.

Comment: I think you have a problem in the concept.Why _you have to_ pass the arguments in the main method?